# Contador de post de un usuario laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Trato de hacer un contador de post que tiene un usuario trato de mostrarlo en una tabla nombre y numero de post

Ok estas son mis relaciones por modelos
Me da el siguiente error
[image: Este es el error]
Modelo Post

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'id_user','id');
}
```

Modelo Usuario

```
 public function Post(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post','id','id_user');
}
```

Esta es mi base de datos
[image: Mis relaciones de bases de datos]

Esta es mi tabla blade donde pienso mostrar el numero de tareas

```
  @foreach($usuarios as $User)
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{$User->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$User->name}}</td>
            <td><a href=""></a>Ir al perfil</td>
            <td><a href="">@foreach($posts as $Post) {{count($Post->user)}} @endforeach</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
```

Mi controlador

```
     public function tabla(){
        $usuarios=User::all();
        $posts=Post::all();
        return view('tabla',compact('usuarios','posts'));
    }
```

Comment: un post tiene un usuario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count()` Es una función nativa de php, que recibe como argumento un array o un elemento contable, puedes leer más sobre esta función [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php).

Cuando pasas `$Post->user` en realidad estás pasando otra cosa, para contar los elementos relacionados puedes utilizar [counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

**Ejemplo de la documentación oficial de laravel**

```
use App\Models\Post;

$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

También puedes obtener la colección y convertirla a un array, tipo de dato admitido por `count();`, para esto puedes utilizar `->toArray()` o si deseas simplemente contar la colección principal puedes utilizar `->count();`.

**Actualización**

Es importante tener en consideración que tanto las relaciones creadas en las migraciones para la base de datos como las definidas en los modelos sean consistentes, del contrario se producirán resultados no deseados.

En tu caso, si el usuario es quien tiene muchos posts y este pertenece solo a un usuario la relación debería ser:

Modelo Usuario

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post', 'id_user','id');
}
```

y los posts:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'id_user');
}
```